# Bargaining problem: show that $S \subset \mathbb R^2$ is convex and compact

Tags: game-theory

There are two agents $i \in \{1,2\}$ who share a dollar. 
The amount agent $i$ receives is denoted with $x_i \in [0,1]$.
The set of feasible allocations is then given by by $X = \{(x_1,x_2) \mid x_1 + x_2 \leq 1\}$.
An agent receives utility according to the function $u_i(x_i) = \sqrt{x_i}$.
Note that $u_i(x_i) \in [0,1]$ for all $x_i \in [0,1]$.
Define the set of feasible outcomes by $S = \{(u_1(x_1),u_2(x_2)) \mid (x_1,x_2) \in X\}$.
For $S$ being a well-defined [bargaining problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bargaining_problem) we need to show that $S$ is convex and compact.

**Convexity** 
We show that $S$ is compact, by showing that the [Pareto frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier) is concave. 
The Pareto frontier is defined by efficient (no waste) allocations $P = \{(u_1(x_1),u_2(x_2)) \mid x_1 + x_2 = 1\}$.
The Pareto frontier is thus the boundary of $S$, i.e., $P \subset \partial S$. 
The inverse of $u_1$ is given by $x_1(u_1) = u_1^2$. 
With $x_1 + x_2 = 1$ it is easy to see that the Pareto frontier is given by the following funtion $u_2(u_1) = \sqrt{1-u_1^2}$.
Since $u''_2(u_1) < 0$ for all $u_1 \in [0,1]$, $S$ is convex.

I was wondering how to show convexity from the primitive definition $\lambda (u_1(y_1),u_2(y_2)) + (1-\lambda)(u_1(z_1),u_2(z_2)) \in S$ for all $y,z \in X$ with $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

I also do not know how one shows compactness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convexity: 
Take arbitrary $y, z \in X$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$.
We need to find a point $x \in X$ such that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda u_{1}(y_{1}) + (1 - \lambda) u_{1}(z_{1})
\\
\lambda u_{2}(y_{2}) + (1 - \lambda) u_{2}(z_{2})
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}(x_{1})
\\
u_{2}(x_{2})
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Our candidate point is $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ with $x_{1} = u_{1}^{-1}\left(\lambda u_{1}(y_{1}) + (1 - \lambda) u_{1}(z_{1})\right)$ and $x_{2} = u_{2}^{-1}\left(\lambda u_{2}(y_{2}) + (1 - \lambda) u_{2}(z_{2})\right)$.
We only have to show that $x_{1} + x_{2} \leq 1$, as otherwise $x$ does not belong to $X$.
This is where concavity of $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ comes in:
By Jensen's inequality and the fact that $u_{1}$ is increasing,
$$
x_{1} = u_{1}^{-1}\left(\lambda u_{1}(y_{1}) + (1 - \lambda) u_{1}(z_{1})\right)
\leq
u_{1}^{-1}\left(u_{1}\left(\lambda y_{1} + (1 - \lambda) z_{1} \right)\right)
=
\lambda y_{1} + (1 - \lambda) z_{1}.
$$
A similar argument shows
$$
x_{2} \leq \lambda y_{2} + (1 - \lambda) z_{2}.
$$
Therefore, $x_{1} + x_{2} \leq \lambda (y_{1} + y_{2}) + (1 - \lambda) (z_{1} + z_{2}) \leq \lambda + (1 - \lambda) = 1$,
where the inequality uses that $y$ and $z$ belong to $X$ by assumption.

Compactness:
Here, use the fact that continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets.
The set $S$ is precisely the image of $X$ under a continuous function.